# Nginx Laravel Route as Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, nginx

I have a Laravel 5 project, the staffs information can be access from testing.com/staffs, but I want to change the URL to testing.com/test/index.php/staffs, I have tried the Laravel Route group using "test/index.php/", but laravel did not support "dot" in route, How can I do that?

the following is my part of nginx.conf

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|css|js)$ {
            expires     max;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return  404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9006;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;`. See [this document](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/).

Comment: Have you tried to prefix your route ?

 `Route::group(['prefix' => 'test/index.php'], function() {
  /* your route here ... */
 });`

Comment: shempignon : Laravel did not support dot in route::group prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Rickard Smith might Right!! the following are the finally code

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9006;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Then you can use Route Group Prefix with "dot" now, Thanks Rickard Smith and shempignon Help!!